# If $alt variable empty then fall back to $title in Wordpress custom function

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I have constructed a custom gallery type as a new shortcode in Wordpress.

However I want to make it a little more SEO friendly so am trying to call the alt tag, and if the alt tag is not found replace it with the title.

So far I have the following (and it works fine) but I am stuck at trying to have $alt fallback to title if $alt is empty? Any ideas/help appreciated!

```
$bigimageUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id,$size='full-size');
$littleimageUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id,$size='thumbnail');
$title_raw = $attachment->post_title;
$title = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", " ", $title_raw);
$alt_raw = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$alt = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", " ", $alt_raw);

echo '<img class="gallerytype" title="'; echo $title; echo '" alt="'; echo $alt; echo '" data-rsTmb="'; echo $littleimageUrl[0]; echo '" src="'; echo $bigimageUrl[0]; echo '"/> ';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) - your problem is that you use regular expressions for that. You need to learn how to parse and process HTML properly first, see the related link.

Comment: @hakra much appreciated! Will give it a read. As you can tell still wrestling with PHP

Comment: My fault, I placed you the wrong link.

Comment: @SMacFadyen to my shame I didn't even realise that it was an option, I was merrily up-voting past ones that worked and leaving it at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using one `echo` after the other:

```
echo '<img class="gallerytype" title="';
echo $title; 
echo '" alt="'; 
echo $alt; echo '" data-rsTmb="'; 
echo $littleimageUrl[0]; 
echo '" src="'; 
echo $bigimageUrl[0]; echo '"/> ';
```

You can use a comma (`,`) to separate expressions to be output:

```
echo '<img class="gallerytype" title="', $title, '" alt="', ..., '"/> ';
```

That should already help you to make the code a little mit more readable.

Then you want to set `$alt` to `$title` if it is empty. So do that before the output:

```
empty($alt) && $alt = $title;
```

Read as: `$alt` is empty and `$alt` is `$title`.

You could also write that with an `if` clause:

```
if (empty($alt)) $alt = $title;
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to do this. Appreciated

Comment: If you're learning PHP @tjh I'd recommend that you use the `if` statement hakra has written for you, rather than the ternary operator. Using an `if` statement makes much more logical sense to users new to PHP, as you can actually read it out loud clearly in your head: `if $alt is empty, alt equals title`. The ternary operator on the other hand (`empty($alt) && $alt = $title;`) makes a little less sense and makes it harder to debug, especially if you come back to the code after a period of time away from it.

Comment: @dunc I prefer to think of it as battling PHP rather than learning it... but yes, advice appreciated, will do this